# Static assets not refreshing with symfony2 clear cache command

Tags: caching, symfony, sass, compass-sass, assetic

I'm using Assetic with the compass filter to pass and compile .scss files. This part of the setup seems to work fine. However, my understanding was that in the app_dev environment, Symfony 2 would recompile all assets (including css) for each page load and not use the caching system that it employs for prod environment.

This seems not to be happening.

When I make a change to a .scss file it will only take effect if I use:

```
 app/console cache:clear
```

I thought the whole point of the dev environment was to avoid having to do this each time?!

I've checked the permissions of the cache folders (to be safe I've set them so anybody can read and write). Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I use Symfony with **less** and it recompiles it on every request, as long as changes are in the actual included file and not in files imported from that one. Maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've found the answer here:

[assetic compass filter, css not updating when changing imported file (google groups discussion)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/l8P3W22dUqw)

It seems that if a change is made to an imported file without any changes to the parent file then the parent file will not be recompiled. The result being the change will not be seen until you force recompilation.

The poster on google groups suggested a possible fix (hack!) by editing the AsseticController. I haven't tried it yet, but even if it works I'd rather not edit a vendor package.

Answer (score 15):

if you are working with symfony 2 assets in dev. environment, simply use [this command](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment):

```
php app/console assets:install
php app/console assetic:dump --watch
```

Since version 2.4 [`--watch` is deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/commit/33532c75b898f4b658a315dfb6047868455afb5e), and has been replaced by:

```
php app/console assetic:watch
```

Comment: details: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Answer (score 3):

Asset compilation is not part of the caching system. You need to re-install assets when you make changes, regardless of the environment.

```
app/console assets:install web
```

If the filesystem you're on supports symbolic links, you can avoid having to run this command for every change and instead just install the assets as such

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

But since you're using Sass, this probably isn't an option for you.

HTH

Comment: Sorry Peter, I should have been clearer. I'm only talking about asset files (css, js) not assets like images. In the docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) it states that in dev environment these assets are handled dynamically and changes should be seen immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic but the only answers I could fine were the CompassElephantBundle and the above AsseticController hack. I've got an approach which is essentially but means I didn't have to edit the vendor package.

The way I have done it is to edit copy the original AsseticController and then linking to that in the config from the parameters.

```
parameters:
    assetic.controller.class: Acme\RandomBundle\Controller\AsseticController
```

The copied AsseticController just does a preg_match for the filetype from the source path and corrects caching from there.

```
<?php

/* Original Assetic Controller */

public function render($name, $pos = null)
{
    if (!$this->enableProfiler && null !== $this->profiler) {
        $this->profiler->disable();
    }

    if (!$this->am->has($name)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The "%s" asset could not be found.', $name));
    }

    $asset = $this->am->get($name);
    if (null !== $pos && !$asset = $this->findAssetLeaf($asset, $pos)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The "%s" asset does not include a leaf at position %d.', $name, $pos));
    }

    $bustCache = preg_match('/\.(scss|sass|less)$/', $asset->getSourcePath());

    $response = $this->createResponse();
    $response->setExpires(new \DateTime());

    if ($bustCache) {
        $lastModified = time();
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $date->setTimestamp($lastModified);
        $response->setLastModified($date);
    }
    else
    {
        // last-modified
        if (null !== $lastModified = $asset->getLastModified()) {
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $date->setTimestamp($lastModified);
            $response->setLastModified($date);
        }
    }

    // etag
    if ($this->am->hasFormula($name)) {
        $formula = $this->am->getFormula($name);
        $formula['last_modified'] = $lastModified;
        $response->setETag(md5(serialize($formula)));
    }

    if ($response->isNotModified($this->request)) {
        return $response;
    }

    if ($bustCache) {
        $response->setContent($asset->dump());
    }
    else {
        $response->setContent($this->cachifyAsset($asset)->dump());
    }

    return $response;
}

/* Rest of controller */
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue in local development by adding a line to the end of my parameters.yml, which basically stops any asset caching from taking place.

```
# parameters.yml
...

assetic.cache.class: Assetic\Cache\ArrayCache
```

This should **never** be included in a production environment as we want caching to happen!

Answer (score 0):

I use different way. I'm adding all .scss files during development

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets filter='?uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite' filter="compass"
            "@TESTSSassBundle/Resources/public/css/_vars.scss" <-- this will be removed
            "@TESTSSassBundle/Resources/public/css/main.scss"
            "@TESTSSassBundle/Resources/public/css/header.scss"
            "@TESTSSassBundle/Resources/public/css/footer.scss"
         %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

and after I finish development I remove them.
This way I do not need to clear my cache and add/change any settings. It always work for me.